# NUnit tests not recognizing gcAllowVeryLargeObjects setting

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory, nunit

I'm using NUnit 3.12, VS 2019, and .Net 4.6.1.

I'm attempting to set the `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true"\>` setting for NUnit tests via the App.config but it doesn't appear to be registering the config change when actually executing the tests.

Here is my App.config for my Test project:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Code that is failing:

```
[Test]
public void TestLargeAllocation()
{
    var x = new double[18000, 18000];
}
```

System.OutOfMemoryException Message: "Array dimensions exceeded supported range."

I have verified that the tests.dll.config in the output directory actually contains the config setting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
    <assemblyBinding xmlns=...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess, that you should add the `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` setting to NUnit test runner config

Comment: Is that different than the tests.dll.config?  Because it is set in there.  Looking at https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Configuration-Files I assume that is the file you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, it seems so

Comment: Exactly! The App.config plays no part in running tests and neither does the config file of the runenr itself. The test.dll.config or equivalent name is what you want.

Comment: Whatever is in the App.config appears to be added to the test.dll.config.  So unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying that doesn't seem to be the issue.